# Complexity of frog game on graphs is exponential, or can we do better?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, time-complexity, trees, decision-problem

Frog game initializes by placing one frog on every vertex of a simple connected graph $G$ with $n$ vertices. A move consists of moving all $x\gt 0$ frogs from one vertex to another non-empty vertex to which a path of $x$ unique edges exists. A vertex is solvable if there is a sequence of $n-1$ moves to move all frogs to that vertex.

Given a graph and a vertex, how efficiently can we decide if the vertex is solvable? We can examine all relevant partitions of the graph, but that is exponential. Can we do better? For simplicity, you can assume that the graph is acyclic (a tree).

This is a generalization of "Lazy toads" from [Frog Jumping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3HDnrehyDM) where they show all vertices of a path graph are solvable. Some examples of the generalization are shown as a slideshow on [mathpickle.com](https://mathpickle.com/project/lazy-toad-puzzles-counting-symmetry/). For example, in a star graph with $n\gt 3$, leaf vertices are not solvable.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you mean by "to which a path of $x$ unique edges exists".  Can you state that more precisely?  Does the path have to start at the vertex where the frogs were?  Is there some context or motivation for this question?  What is meant by a "non-empty" vertex?

Comment: You can produce Recamán's sequence by playing the game on an infinite path graph. I wonder if the difficulty of these two problems are at all related?

Comment: @D.W. Yes, the path starts at the vertex from which you are moving the frogs. For example, one frog must jump to its neighboring vertices, two frogs must jump over their neighboring vertices... "Non-empty" means that at least one frog is there (frogs can't jump to vertices with 0 frogs). For context and motivation, it is a generalization of  the "Lazy toads" problem (click the youtube link).

Comment: @ExaltedToast Interesting observation, but going from finite to infinite and also considering a specific sequence of jumps, seems like a different league of problems.

Comment: Decided to ask about complexity class on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/432689/88524).

Comment: You can treat the problem as finding a weighted tree with the edges+weights as moves of groups between nodes. Then the problem is a relatively straightforward ILP over some sums (or SAT in this case) to find an appropriate adjacency matrix, which seems marginally easier than the original problem. That said, intuitively it feels like it isn't anything better than a special case of SAT, but no concrete proof.